# Direction Cosine Matrix implementation

Tags: java, android, matrix, direction, trigonometry

I'm trying to implement the Direction Cosine Matrix on Android. I've read some theory about DCM and I finally coded a draft

```
public void imuUpdate(float dT, float gyro[], float accel[]) {

        int i;
        Tuple3d Kacc = new Tuple3d();

        // Acc can estimate global K vector(zenith) measured in body's
        // coordinate systems (the reverse of gravitation vector)
        Kacc.x = -accel[0];
        Kacc.y = -accel[1];
        Kacc.z = -accel[2];

        // vector3d_normalize(Kacc);
        Kacc.normalize();
        // calculate correction vector to bring dcmGyro's K vector closer to Acc
        // vector (K vector according to accelerometer)
        Tuple3d wA = new Tuple3d();
        Tuple3d dcmGyroX = new Tuple3d();
        dcmGyroX.x = dcm_matrix.get(0, 2);
        dcmGyroX.y = dcm_matrix.get(1, 2);
        dcmGyroX.z = dcm_matrix.get(2, 2);

        wA.cross(dcmGyroX, Kacc);


        // calculate correction vector to bring dcmGyro's I vector closer to Mag
        // vector (I vector according to magnetometer)
        Tuple3d Imag = new Tuple3d();
        Tuple3d wM = new Tuple3d();

        // in the absense of magnetometer let's assume North vector (I) is
        // always in XZ plane of the device (y coordinate is 0)
        Imag.x = Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow(dcm_matrix.get(0, 2), 2));
        Imag.y = 0;
        Imag.z = dcm_matrix.get(0, 2);

        dcmGyroX.x = dcm_matrix.get(0, 0);
        dcmGyroX.y = dcm_matrix.get(1, 0);
        dcmGyroX.z = dcm_matrix.get(2, 0);

        wM.cross(dcmGyroX, Imag);

        // ---------------
        // dcmGyro
        // ---------------

        Tuple3d w = new Tuple3d();
        // Acc can estimate global K vector(zenith) measured in body's
        // coordinate systems (the reverse of gravitation vector)
        w.x = -gyro[0];
        w.y = -gyro[1];
        w.z = -gyro[2];

        float wA2[] = new float[3];

        wA2[0] = (float) wA.x;
        wA2[1] = (float) wA.y;
        wA2[2] = (float) wA.z;

        w.x *= dT; 
        w.x = (w.x + ACC_WEIGHT * wA.x + MAG_WEIGHT * wM.x)
                / (1.0 + ACC_WEIGHT + MAG_WEIGHT);

        w.y *= dT;
        w.y = (w.y + ACC_WEIGHT * wA.y + MAG_WEIGHT * wM.y)
                / (1.0 + ACC_WEIGHT + MAG_WEIGHT);

        w.z *= dT; 
        w.z = (w.z + ACC_WEIGHT * wA.z + MAG_WEIGHT * wM.z)
                / (1.0 + ACC_WEIGHT + MAG_WEIGHT);

        dcm_rotate(w);

    }

// rotate DCM matrix by a small rotation given by angular rotation vector w
    // see  
    public void dcm_rotate(Tuple3d w) {
        // float W[3][3];
        // creates equivalent skew symetric matrix plus identity matrix
        // vector3d_skew_plus_identity((float*)w,(float*)W);
        // float dcmTmp[3][3];
        // matrix_multiply(3,3,3,(float*)W,(float*)dcm,(float*)dcmTmp);

        Tuple3d dcmXX = new Tuple3d();
        Tuple3d dcmXY = new Tuple3d();
        Tuple3d dcmXZ = new Tuple3d();

        dcmXX.x = dcm_matrix.get(0, 0);
        dcmXX.y = dcm_matrix.get(1, 0);
        dcmXX.z = dcm_matrix.get(2, 0);

        dcmXY.x = dcm_matrix.get(0, 1);
        dcmXY.y = dcm_matrix.get(1, 1);
        dcmXY.z = dcm_matrix.get(2, 1);

        dcmXZ.x = dcm_matrix.get(0, 2);
        dcmXZ.y = dcm_matrix.get(1, 2);
        dcmXZ.z = dcm_matrix.get(2, 2);

        Tuple3d dR = new Tuple3d();

        dR.cross(w, dcmXX);
        dcmXX.add(dR);
        // System.out.println("WA:  " + w.x + " " + w.y + " " + w.z);
        dR.cross(w, dcmXY);
        dcmXY.add(dR);

        dR.cross(w, dcmXZ);
        dcmXZ.add(dR);

        // Orthonormalize
        Tuple3d dcmXXtmp = dcmXX;
        Tuple3d dcmXYtmp = dcmXY;
        Tuple3d dcmXZtmp = dcmXZ;

        // err = X . Y , X = X - err/2 * Y , Y = Y - err/2 * X (DCMDraft2
        // Eqn.19)
        // float err = vector3d_dot((float*)(dcm[0]),(float*)(dcm[1]));
        float err = (float) dcmXX.Dot(dcmXY);

        dcmXXtmp.scaleAdd(-err / 2, dcmXY);
        dcmXYtmp.scaleAdd(-err / 2, dcmXX);

        dcmXZtmp.cross(dcmXXtmp, dcmXYtmp);

        dcmXXtmp.normalize();
        dcmXYtmp.normalize();
        dcmXZtmp.normalize();

        dcm_matrix.set(0, 0, (float) dcmXXtmp.x);
        dcm_matrix.set(1, 0, (float) dcmXXtmp.y);
        dcm_matrix.set(2, 0, (float) dcmXXtmp.z);

        dcm_matrix.set(0, 1, (float) dcmXYtmp.x);
        dcm_matrix.set(1, 1, (float) dcmXYtmp.y);
        dcm_matrix.set(2, 1, (float) dcmXYtmp.z);

        dcm_matrix.set(0, 2, (float) dcmXZtmp.x);
        dcm_matrix.set(1, 2, (float) dcmXZtmp.y);
        dcm_matrix.set(2, 2, (float) dcmXZtmp.z);

    }
```

So every time the Gyro get updated I compute dT and I call imuUpdate

I achieved to do this code by mixing the theory http://gentlenav.googlecode.com/files/DCMDraft2.pdf and some code found here http://code.google.com/p/picquadcontroller/source/browse/trunk/imu.h?r=7 (thanks to them by the way)

But I can make this DCM work... if I try to extract the pitch for example

```
pitch = Math.asin(-dcm_matrix.get(0, 2));
```

the result it's completly wrong (it's giving me some random angles...) and if i plot the DCM well it's numbers... But I can't figure out where in my calculation I'm wrong...

Can somebody give me a hand on this please?

**EDIT:**
I have updated my code (i had a sign error). Now I tested my DCM after what ALi suggested (corss product on 2 diferent must be 0 or almost 0 and the square sum must be 1 or almost 1 on my case)

Well.. I tried to apply my DCM using opengl

```
gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -10.0f);


     // setup code
        float vertexData[] = new float[16];

        for (int i=0;i<16;i++)
        {
            vertexData[i] = 0;
        }

        vertexData[15] = 1;


        vertexData[0] = this.main.dcm_matrix.mMat[0];
        vertexData[1] = this.main.dcm_matrix.mMat[1];
        vertexData[2] = this.main.dcm_matrix.mMat[2];
        vertexData[3] = this.main.dcm_matrix.mMat[3];
        vertexData[5] = this.main.dcm_matrix.mMat[4];
        vertexData[6] = this.main.dcm_matrix.mMat[5];
        vertexData[8] = this.main.dcm_matrix.mMat[6];
        vertexData[9] = this.main.dcm_matrix.mMat[7];
        vertexData[10] = this.main.dcm_matrix.mMat[8];


       gl.glMultMatrixf(vertexData,0);
```

I beg pardon for that crap coding I don't wanted to do algorithme error so.. i put the value one by one :).
so my DCM is 3x3 but following that video he says that opengl use a 4x4 (with zero on the edge and a ONE on the last diago element) thats why all thos stuff on thos code I just showed.

And the result is really bad.  depending on how I move my phone I can see a little cube rotating really fast in every direction.... SO I don't know is the mistake now

Thank you

Comment: One way to check the dcm matrix is: check if the sum of the squre of the elements in one row equals 1. The same is true for the columns. Then check if the dot product of (different) rows equals 0. Same for the columns. Altogether it is six things to check. These are the conditions on page 6 of the DCMDraft. If these are correct then the DCM matrix should be OK. Plese do not use roll, pitch and yaw, they are evil.

Comment: @Ali Ah yes.. I really need to read more carefully that paper... I did those check and the cross product 0 that's ok. But the sum of the square sometime is negative? for example -0.9999031 -0.0047487 0.013120476 it gives me -1... I would say that on average I got half 1.0 and half -1 –.  And if it is not recomended to use euler angle How can I use my DCM?

Comment: You should compute the square of the elements first then the sum: x^2+y^2+z^2. As the square function is non-negative it is impossible to get a negative number, I have no idea how you got -1, sorry :( What would you like to **do** with roll, pitch and yaw? Anything you can do with Euler angles you can do that with the DCM too.

Comment: @Ali Oh ok my bad, there was a little mistake in the code. Now i get more or less :) 1 (max 1.2, min 0.93 I think it's quite good) when i sum and 0 if a cross. I like to visualise stuff so I tried to use opengl to get my DCM in action. I just created a simple cube and I use glMultMatrixf to apply the rotation with my DCM but it's not working (for a change ;) )

Comment: Well, in my applicaton I get values between 0.99999 and 1.00001. What sampling frequncy are you using? I perform a measurement every 5 ms. As for visualizing the DCM, I use OpenGL too.

Comment: Hello Ali, sorry for the late reply I was quite busy those days.. So i displayed the squares sum and there is obviously a problem.If the phone is placed on a flat table the 6 square sum start at 1.0000 and they all increased trough time - at i would say - 0.0001 each second so after half a minute they are all at over 1.5 or 2...

Comment: I gave up. I can't make the DCM work properly